# Magento "customer/account_navigation"

Tags: magento

I would like to include links from My Account ("customer/account_navigation") at the top as well as on the side of once customer is logged in - so these links are accessible directly in the header.

I have created

```
<reference name="header">
    <block type="customer/account_navigation" name="customer_account_navigation_header" template="customer/account/navigation.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

in my `local.xml`, and then used

`$this->getChildHtml('customer_account_navigation_header');`.

What am I missing???

Comment: How do you get it managed to add the customer account navigation to the header? Using your method only display it on the account subpages, but not globally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you remember to `echo` that statement (gets me more often than it should)? Next steps are to (1) verify that your custom header template is being used and (2) clear out the `block_html` cache as the header is cached by default.

Comment: lol, obviously I had to forgot to echo - long working hours and too much coffee!!!